# Spring STS Install issue Version 1.6.0_67 of JVM not suitable

Tags: spring

I have problem launching STS application. I have downloaded Win 64 bit that matches my system and I have jdk 1.8 installed. That is the only version I have.
I am getting the following error when I launch STS
"version 1.7.0_67 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version:1.8 or greater is required"

Comment: Open cmd prompt and type `java -version` to verify if you have version 1.8.

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\z018746>java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

Comment: Dude I have mentioned already. I am having only the jdk 1.8 version in my system. See the cmd log generated in the previous comment. Can you help me further please?

Comment: The only reason why your STS is not working is either because you dont have JAVA properly installed or because your STS version(32bit/64bit) is not compatible with your windows.

Comment: Thank you. As you said I have installed 32 bit instead of 64 bit.

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: Yeah its working now. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason why your `STS` is not working is either because you don't have `JAVA` properly installed or because your `STS` `version(32bit/64bit)` is not compatible with your windows.

Make sure both of these things are fixed.